# Implementing "computable phase shifts" using T Toffoli ( problem 4.1 from Nielsen and Chuang's)

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

I am reading/studying the famous Nielsen and Chuang's book and ran into this interesting question and I don't quite understand the $f(x)$.  It says it simply maps from $m$ to $n$ bits.  But don't we have to know what $f(x)$ is to build a circuit using Ts and CNOTs? I think I miss something here.

Thanks.

> Problem 4.1: (Computable phase shifts) Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers.
> Suppose $f:\left\{0, \ldots, 2^{m}-1\right\} \rightarrow\left\{0, \ldots, 2^{n}-1\right\}$ is a classical function from $m$ to $n$ bits which may be computed reversibly using $T$ Toffoli gates, as described in Section 3.2.5. That is, the function $(x, y) \rightarrow(x, y \oplus f(x))$ may be implemented using $T$ Toffoli gates. Give a quantum circuit using $2 T+n$ (or fewer) one, two, and three qubit gates to implement the unitary operation defined by
> $$
> |x\rangle \rightarrow \exp \left(\frac{-2 i \pi f(x)}{2^{n}}\right)|x\rangle .
> $$

Comment: Have you thought about treating $f$ as a black box?  For example can you treat $f$ abstractly and construct a circuit of $2T+n$ qubit gates to convert the values of $f$ into phases and use those to conditionally rotate the amplitude of $\vert x\rangle$?

Comment: @MarkS   I will think about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would go as follows:

1. Compute $\hat P|x,y\rangle \equiv |x,y \oplus f(x)\rangle$ using $T$ Toffoli gates.
2. Expand $q=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} q_j 2^j$ with $q_j$ being the digits of a binary representation of $0\le q\le 2^{n-1}$.
3. Now observe that
   \begin{align*}
      \hat O|x,q\rangle&\equiv\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm iyn/2^n}\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(-\pi\mathrm i q_j2^{j-n+1}\right) \Bigg|x,q\bigg\rangle \\
   &= \exp\left(-2\pi\mathrm i/2^n\left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}q_j2^j-y\right)\right) \Bigg|x,q\bigg\rangle \\
   &= \exp\left(-2\pi\mathrm i/2^n\left(q-y\right)\right) |x,q\rangle,
   \end{align*}
   so that for $q = y\oplus f(x)$, we obtain $\hat O|x,y\oplus f(x)\rangle=\exp\left(-2\pi\mathrm i/2^nf(x)\right)|x,y\oplus f(x)\rangle.$
   The operation $\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(-\pi\mathrm i q_j2^{j-n+1}\right)$ can be implemented using $n$ single-qubit phase gates $\hat U_{n-1}\cdots\hat U_0$ each acting as $\hat U_j=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\mathrm e^{-\pi\mathrm i 2^{j-n+1}}\end{pmatrix}$ while the *global* $y$-dependent phase can be neglected.
4. Uncompute $\hat P^\dagger|x,y \oplus f(x)\rangle = |x,y\rangle$, using $T$ Toffoli gates.

The total cost of the operation $\hat P^\dagger\hat O\hat P$ therefore is $2T+n$ gates, as required.